# Consequences of locking a table that is acted upon via triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, locking

Let's say I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`. `t1` has a trigger upon it so that on every INSERT an INSERT then happens on `t2`.

If I then acquire a write lock on `t2`, what happens when I INSERT into `t1`? There are a number of things I'm curious about here:

1. Can I still INSERT into `t1`? Or will it lock?
2. If I can INSERT into `t1` just fine, does that mean that the trigger will be queued up, just waiting until I UNLOCK `t2`?
3. If I'm INSERTing many things into `t1` while I still have the lock on `t2`, are there any consequences to DB performance overall? Will this keep connections open or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `t1` will be not be [locked implicitly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-triggers.html), as the docs for implicit locking explain would be the case if you were doing the reverse (locking `t1` will lock `t2`
2. A MySQL Error (ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table `t1` was not locked with LOCK TABLES) will be generated on attempting to insert into `t1` because it has not been locked, but the destination of its trigger has.
3. N/A, the query to write to `t1` is not permitted by the MySQL engine.

Please consider your use case here however. If you are simply copying INSERTS into another table, and not calculating something, you might want to give a thought to using replication instead.

Verified on MySQL 5.1 with the following SQL of a toy action log:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS acts, actions;

CREATE TABLE acts
(
  act_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  user_id int unsigned not null
)
ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE actions
(
  action_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  act_id int unsigned not null,
  user_id int unsigned not null
)
ENGINE=innodb;

DELIMITER #

CREATE TRIGGER acts_post_ins_trigger AFTER INSERT ON acts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO actions(act_id, user_id) VALUES (new.act_id, new.user_id);
END#

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO acts VALUES(1,2);

SELECT * FROM acts;
SELECT * FROM actions;

LOCK TABLE actions WRITE;

SELECT('trying to SELECT acts w/ actions locked...') AS 'SELECT TEST';
SELECT * FROM acts;
SELECT('trying to INSERT into acts w/ actions locked...') AS 'INSERT TEST';
INSERT INTO acts VALUES(3,4);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Thanks, Shelhamer. I read the docs about the implicit locks, but I was under the impression that they were talking about triggers _of the locked table_, not triggers _on other tables, which interact with a locked table_. If, as you say, it's whether the source or destination are locked, that's informative. My use case is actually considerably more complex than this (looking to ALTER a table in production using this method), but the notice is well received for the general case.

Comment: I am speaking from memory on a big MySQL/PHP site here, and have not re-tested this, but I believe it to be correct. If I have time to verify this during lunch I'll let you know.

Comment: @umbrae, I have just tested this in a DB and my original answer was in fact correct: a MySQL error will be thrown because the tables involved in the trigger have not all been locked. Implicit locking only occurs when the table that is the *source* of the trigger is locked.

Comment: Thanks Shelhamer. If you happen to have your test script handy I'm sure I and anyone else who sees this would love to see it!

Comment: I added the sql I used to test so you can verify the ERROR behavior.